# Export test cases to CSV in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, testcase, export-csv

Can anybody help me with export test cases to CSV? If I have more than one line in one step, then the next step is not a correct export to CSV and is skipped when formatting.

E.g.:

- 1st step = 1 line
- 2nd step = 3 lines
- 3rd step = 1 line
- 4th step = 1 line

= In CSV will be only 1st step, 2nd step and 4th step displayed. 3rd step is skipped

Comment: After testing this myself I suggest you avoind having multi-line steps..

Answer (score 0):

I tested the export option in the `Define` tab in the new Test Plans experience, as shown below. On my side, exporting test cases to csv works well.

[image]

My test case steps:

[image]

Exporting test cases to csv:

[image]

As troubleshooting, you can try to turn off the **New Test Plans Page** in the **Preview features**, refresh back to the page. Then turn on New Test Plans Page again, try `export` option again.

[image]

Here is the relevant [document](https://pkuma-msft.github.io/azure-test-plans/articles/testcase-import-export-csv.html) you can refer to.